# Fitting polytomous logistic regression with R

Tags: r, self-study, logistic

I'm running into troubles fitting a polytomous logistic regression model using grouped data. The data are of the form (dput at bottom):

```
> head(alligator)
    lake  sex  size    food count
1 Hancock male small    fish     7
2 Hancock male small  invert     1
3 Hancock male small reptile     0
4 Hancock male small    bird     0
5 Hancock male small   other     5
6 Hancock male large    fish     4
```

And I've tried to fit the model with `vglm()` from package VGAM:

```
> result <- vglm(food~lake+size+sex, data=alligator, fam=multinomial, weights=count)
Error in if (max(abs(ycounts - round(ycounts))) > smallno) warning("converting 'ycounts' to integer in @loglikelihood") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In checkwz(wz, M = M, trace = trace, wzepsilon = control$wzepsilon) :
  96 elements replaced by 1.819e-12
```

It was also suggested to look at `mlogit()` from package `globaltest` (on Bioconductor), but it does not appear to support grouped data. It obviously doesn't support the `weights` parameter, but I can't find where the equivalent parameter is documented:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("globaltest")

result <- mlogit(food~lake+size+sex, weights=count, data=alligator)
Error in mlogit(food ~ lake + size + sex, weights = count, data = alligator) : 
  unused argument(s) (weights = count)
```

If anyone could put me down the right path, I'd appreciate it!

```
> dput(alligator)
structure(list(lake = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("George", "Hancock", 
"Oklawaha", "Trafford"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("female", 
"male"), class = "factor"), size = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("large", 
"small"), class = "factor"), food = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("bird", 
"fish", "invert", "other", "reptile"), class = "factor"), count = c(7L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 16L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 7L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
9L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 
6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 10L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L)), .Names = c("lake", "sex", "size", "food", "count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I think the class notes need to be updated. This seems to work and matches the output from the course notes. First, reshape the date into wide format:

```
require(reshape2)
a2 <- dcast(lake + sex + size ~ food, data = alligator, value.var="count")
```

Then fit the model with a matrix of responses. The last level passed in becomes the reference level for the models that are fit (fish in this case):

```
result2 <- vglm(cbind(bird, invert, other, reptile, fish) ~ lake + sex + size, 
               data = a2, family = multinomial)
```

Comment: Did you try bringing your `Count` variable in as an `integer` type rather than a `long` type? That was what the error was telling you. R looks at the variable type, not the actual variable data.

Comment: @Michelle - unless I'm missing something, `count` is an integer (as it is fed into `vglm()`). See `> class(alligator$count)
[1] "integer"`

Comment: Hmm... did you try a `traceback()` when you got your error?

Comment: @Michelle. Good thought. I looked at traceback and it looks like it drops down into an internal function `vglm.fitter()`. I'll do some more digging and report back.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [vglm documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VGAM/versions/1.1-3/topics/vglm),

> The values of weights must be positive; try setting a very small value
> such as 1.0e-8 to effectively delete an observation.

Meaning, they can't be zero as in your dataset. So if you'd do something like

```
alligator$count <- pmax(alligator$count, 1e-8)
```

before calling the vglm you should be good to go.